# How to : redactor.js Knockout.js Binder

Tags: knockout.js, redactor

I am using this awesome editor, but I have no idea how to bind the content to knockout:

http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a two-way binding handler which does the job.  As usual with such handlers, the `update` function passes changes from the VM to the UI element (the Redactor element), and the `init` passes changes from Redactor back to the VM.

When I posted this it was for Redactor 9, I've now updated it for Redactor 10.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.redactor = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();

        // We only want Redactor to notify our value of changes if the value
        // is an observable (rather than a string, say).

        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            $(element).redactor({
                changeCallback: value
            });
        }

    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        // New value, note that Redactor expects the argument passed to 'set'
        // to have toString method, which is why we disjoin with ''.

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || '';

        // We only call 'set' if the content has changed, as we only need to
        // to do so then, and 'set' also resets the cursor position, which
        // we don't want happening all the time.

        // This code would work with Redactor 9, but no longer works with Redactor 10
        //if (value !== $(element).redactor('get')) {
        //    $(element).redactor('set', value);
        //}

        // The API method has become 'code.get', and it behaves a bit differently: it
        // returns formatted HTML, i.e. with whitespace and EOLs.  That means that we
        // would update the Redactor content every time the observable changed, which
        // was bad.  So instead we can use this:
        if (value !== $(element).redactor('core.getTextarea').val()) {
            $(element).redactor('code.set', value );
        }
   }

}
```

If the KO observable for the content you want to edit using Redactor is `content` then you could do:

```
<textarea data-bind="redactor: content"></textarea>
```

To get the above working with Redactor 10, you'll have to make a couple of changes.  First of all, you must use 'code.set' and 'code.get', rather than simply 'set' and 'get', for interacting with the HTML.  But if you do only that, you'll find that the HTML returned by 'code.get'

Comment: With a more complicated binding handler you could interact with other bits of Redactor, e.g.

`<textarea data-bind="redactor: {html: content, imageURL: '/images' + id()}"></textarea>`

But the above simple binding handler illustrates the "difficult" part mentioned in the question though, i.e. the binding of the content.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this! I extended it slightly so you can pass in (any) options to it: http://jsfiddle.net/gm9ygp0v/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is it right way or not, but this code works for me:

Creating new binding handler:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.imperavi =
    {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings)
            {
                var startValue = allBindings().value();
                var $el = $(element);
                $el.val(startValue).change();
                $el.redactor({
                    changeCallback: function(html)
                    {
                        $el.val(html).change();
                    }
                });
            }
    };
```

In HTML:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: Text, imperavi: true"></textarea>
```

ViewModel:

```
var VM = function()
{
    this.Text = ko.observable('<p>Hello world</p>');
};

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated dvijaz's Redactor 10 version to support the new Redactor 2 version (thanks dvijaz!):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.redactor = {

init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    var value = valueAccessor();

    // We only want Redactor to notify our value of changes if the value
    // is an observable (rather than a string, say).

    if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        $(element).redactor({ callbacks: { change: value } });
    }

},

update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    // New value, note that Redactor expects the argument passed to 'set'
    // to have toString method, which is why we disjoin with ''.

    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || '';

    // We only call 'set' if the content has changed, as we only need to
    // to do so then, and 'set' also resets the cursor position, which
    // we don't want happening all the time.

    // This code would work with Redactor 9, but no longer works with Redactor 10
    //if (value !== $(element).redactor('get')) {
    //    $(element).redactor('set', value);
    //}

    // The API method has become 'code.get', and it behaves a bit differently: it
    // returns formatted HTML, i.e. with whitespace and EOLs.  That means that we
    // would update the Redactor content every time the observable changed, which
    // was bad.  So instead we can use this:
    if (value !== $(element).redactor('core.textarea').val()) {
        $(element).redactor('code.set', value);
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea that I ***should*** be able to use knockoutjs and redactorjs independently of each other. When redactorjs updates the textarea, knockoutjs should take over and update the model through it's binding.

What I found was that redactorjs is not propagating the change event when the  textarea changes.  To resolve this, I added it manually:

```js
$('textarea').each(function() {
  var textareaEl = $(this);
  textareaEl.redactor({
    blurCallback: function() {
      textareaEl.change();
    }
  });
});
```

<del>There's room for improvement here as this appears changeCallback gets triggered on every key event as well.</del>  But this solution works and doesn't make redactorjs become a dependency in your knockoutjs app (or break when redactor versions change).

**Edit:** I found an undocumented blurCallback in the source of redactorjs. Replaced the use of changeCallback which seems to trigger on keyUp.